# PHP - Accessing POST variable from one file to the another?

Tags: php

so if I have a file:

### test1.php

which has a variable `$var1 = $_POST['username'];`

is there anyway I can access that variable in another file:

### test2.php

```
echo $var1;
```

without having to set a session?
as currently It produces an undefined error

Comment: I'm guessing the post goes to test1.php, which then redirects the user to test2.php ... ?

Comment: pass it via querystring, include test1 in test2 possibly

Comment: yes... one way would be to pass `$var1` value as a `GET` param to `test2.php`, in the event that `test2.php` is a link etc. from within `test1.php`... if not, then the only other way I can think of is by using `$_SESSION`, as you alluded to, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `include 'test1.php';` in test2.php.
Then `echo $var1;` in test2.php.

Comment: that creates an error saying that $var1 is undefined

Comment: I agree with @TessRay97 --- in order for `$var1` to **NOT** be *undefined* is to execute `test2.php` such that it has a `$_POST` param... then it should be okay... otherwise, not so!